# Compartmentalisation and Design of Classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, class-design

In my spare time, I've been taking code I've written for various purposes and appropriating them into other languages just to have a look at what's out there. Currently I'm taking a genetic programming graph colouring algorithm, originally written in Java, and trying to coerce it into C++.

The arbitrary data structure I'm using for the task has a few classes. In Java, it wasn't so much of an issue for me because I had been exposed to it for a while. The graph structure was only created once, and a `Colouring` was assigned to that. The `Colouring` (specifically finding a mostly optimal one) was the real point of the code. I could have a `Graph` class with inner classes like `Node` and `Edge`, for instance, or I could have a package `graph` with classes `Graph`, `Node`, `Edge`, etc.

The first case above might lend itself well to my idea of C++. A main *.cpp file might have some classes `Node`, `Graph`, `Edge`, defined in it. But this seems to really be missing the point of C++, from what I can tell. I'm just taking what I wrote in Java and *forcing* it into C++, adding destructors where appropriate and turning object references to pointers. I'm not yet *thinking* in C++. Do these classes bear separating into separate *.cpp files? Should they be separated, and then compiled as a library to use in the main program? What I really need are some good resources or contrived examples (or even rules of thumb) to say, in C++ programming, what are the different options that exist and when is it a good idea to thinking about one over the other?

---

EDIT: I've been asked by @Pawel Zubrycki to provide some example code. I'm not going to do this, because each component is fairly trivial - It generally has a reference to the next thing, and some get/set methods. I will, however, describe it.

It's essentially an incidence list. There is some unnecessary use of classes termed `...Pointer` - they were a product of a literal translation of a diagram first used to explain incidence lists to me.

There is a container class, `VertexList`, which contains a head element `VertexPointer`, and methods to add new `VertexPointer` objects (Adding it to the graph, but not connecting it to any other nodes, allowing searches to search non-connected graphs), naive search for indices on `Vertex` objects, etc. Every `VertexPointer` has a `Vertex` object, as well as a `VertexPointer next;`, and all those handy `hasNext()` methods that you might expect. A `Vertex` also has an associated `ConnectionList`

The same is duplicated for `EdgeList`, `EdgePointer`, and `Edge`, except that an `Edge` is associated with two `Connection` objects.

`ConnectionList` and `Connection`: `ConnectionList` mimicking `VertexList` or `EdgeList`, having a `Connection head;` and all those handy methods you might expect, like `addConnection()`. A `Connection` has an `Edge` associated with it, as well as some `Connection next;`

This allows us to easily get the connected components of any one point in the graph, and have an arbitrary number of connections.

---

It seems pretty over-the-top complicated, but the same functionality could be duplicated with some `LinkedList` of `Vertex` objects, a `LinkedList` of `Edge` objects, and a number of `LinkedList` of `Connection` objects. The `LinkedList` of `Vertex` Objects allows us to iterate over all Vertices for exhaustive searches on Vertices, and the same applies for edges. The `LinkedList` objects of `Connection` allow us to quickly traverse to any connected Vertices and to arbitrarily add or connections in the graph. This step up in complexity was added to deal with the complexity of evaluating a certain colouring of a graph (weighted edges, quick traversal of local subgraphs, etc.)

Comment: This question is better suited at programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997924/c-best-practices

Comment: @Gunner - I believe this question is suited to both sites. While it does fit (and perhaps better) under things like "Architecture" and "Design Patterns" listed for programmers.stackexchange.com, this is a specific programming problem I'm seeking the answer to, for a specific language. I'm not asking what OOP is, or about certain design patterns in a language agnostic way. @Simone - That is an interesting read, but the links there do not address my question. However, I think I will be having a read of this in my spare time as well. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have classes like `Node`, `Graph` and `Edge`, and their implementation is not too large, it makes perfectly good sense to define them in one and the same .cpp file. After all, they are meant to be used together.

In C++, a package like this is called a component. Usually it makes more sense to think in components than classes, since C++ is not only an OOP language and classes are not always the preferred way do things.

If you want to learn more about the preferred way to organize code in C++, I recommend [Large Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620).

BTW: Making a library out of these classes really seems overkill.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit, the data structure used is an incidence list, and is slightly more complicated than just `Node`, `Edge`, etc. The data structure itself probably isn't worthy of a library, but there is a possibility of implementing a lot of functionality there with regards to searches and whatnot that I may also additionally specify. Is it the complexity of the component, or the scale of functionality that should determine when to look at components versus libraries? Thank you also for the reference - I've added that one to my To Read list.

Comment: It is a very open-ended question. But one idea may be too have a look at Boost.Graph. It is complicated, but generally considered to be very well designed. Here is a description of its adjacency list implementation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html

Comment: ...and about components versus libraries: This is not really a matter of code organization, as much as code distribution. After all, libraries contain components.

Comment: I shall have a look at their implementation, but in the end this isn't for production code or anything of any point, other than my practice of a language I'm not familiar with. I would much prefer to implement a basic data structure that suits my needs than lift and use another, even if it is faster, leaner, and not full of SIGSEGVs (Expecting this one a bit). I appreciate your answer regarding components versus libraries - distribution is not something I had paid any heed.

Comment: Yes, it's good to implement for yourself - I was more thinking Boost.Graph could give some design ideas.